# Excel is not sorting letter correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have a weird problem with Excel: it is sorting the letter "CH" incorrectly (it places "CH" after "CZ"). As you can see in the attached image, it only happens with "CH" and not with any other combination like "AH", "DH". Anyone has an idea what is going on?

[sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuQLY.png)

Comment: This may be a function of the language setting in Excel or your system. I believe, for example, that Spanish considers 'CH' to be a separate letter from 'C', and sorts between 'CZ' and 'DA'. Could this be what you are running into?

Comment: The Excel setting was already English (US) but the Windows region setting was my country local. Going to Control Panel and change Region to English (US) fixed the issue. Thank you very much for the quick answer.

Comment: I've converted my comment to an answer; I'd appreciate it if you'd Accept it (click the check mark) to show that it did indeed address your issue (it additionally throws me a little rep).

Comment: The D's are perfectly sorted.  Are you sure you selected the correct column?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat - Except for the CH digraph, so was the C column. Note that the querent has in fact confirmed that the issue was his system language setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the querent’s response to a suggestion in the comments, it appears that Excel uses the system language setting for sorting. As such, if the language is one that considers the ***CH*** digraph a separate letter from ***C***, this issue may occur in sorting. See [Wikipedia on the CH digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_(digraph)) for more information; Spanish is one of several languages that might cause this issue.